# Class Restriction in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, restriction

I was trying Google App Engine to build a sample application using Eclipse plugin. I tried creating a HttsURLConnection class in my code, and the editor showed a RED mark complaining 'javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment', I was wondering how this is being done, is it done by GAE plugin that I have installed? How is this accomplished? I have JRE System Library[jdk1.6.0_27] in my class path.

I think it is a compile time check?

Are they restricting access using policy files which I think is a runtime behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is a restriction related probably to the sandbox environment of Google App Engine platform where "Applications run in a secure environment that provides limited access to the underlying operating system". Also it appears that you're not the only one with this problem: see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/ZEskGLwyE_0), specially the part where says that "HttpsURLConnection is not currently available and we should remove the reference to it from the documentation"

Comment: I understand that google has restricted access to certain classes of Java and they also have different implementation for certain java classes. My question was on eclipse, as how eclipse tags these classes as forbidden in the editor? the mechanism with which they tag it as forbidden